# How to efficienctly find the top border line of a graph in python

Tags: python, algorithm, graph, union, polygon

I have a set of graphs from which I want to find an outline graph (Black line in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XJYtN.png) figure.)

Finding the maximum of each graph at all points on the x-axis is not possible because the x-values are not same for all the graphs. The points are accurate to a couple of decimal places. [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wblID.png) figure might be able to help understand better.

I tried converting each graph to a polygon and using shapely cascaded_union and then cropping off the bottom.
It works for a small number of graphs, but when the number of graphs becomes large. It takes a lot of time.

Is there some other efficient way to do this?

Comment: How are the graphs represented? Can you just get the `max` of all the graphs for each point?

Comment: That is not possible because an x values are accurate to decimal places, and an x value might not have a value for each graph.

Comment: Do I understand it correct that when there is no measurement at some value x, you 1) do linear interpolation between measurements that belong together (same color) and surround x and 2) take the maximum of these interpolations at x?

Comment: Yes Exactly. But doing that for a large set of data takes too long.

Comment: Does this https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_hull_algorithms solve the problem?

Comment: Convex hull skips a lot of points in between.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort all your points by their x coordinate.

Your final output will have a finite number of pixels. You can compute the range of x values that fall within each pixel(small range but not 0). So split your points into buckets. Since they are already sorted, you just need to advance through the list until the values belongs to the next range.

For each pixel column compute the maximum y value you find. Add a point at the (x, y) for the black line.

The complexity of this will be o(N logN).

If you have gaps on the x axis you can choose to either skip it and have a gap in the black line or simply interpolate between the neighbouring values. If you plot the blackline as a collection of line segments you can just skip generating a point for that column and let the renderer do the interpolation for you.

If your original points are too rare (they skip pixels) your line may look jagged (jumping up and down). You can avoid this by adding interpolated values for the functions that don't have a point in that range. Linear interpolation should work just fine. Make sure you generate try to generate a point at the beginning and the end of the interval and take the larger y-value.